# LC3: TRAP x21 not working properly in simple program. Shows as TRAP xD0 in simulator

Tags: assembly, lc3

I'm writing a program that takes an input number (n) from 0-9 and outputs its double (2n).

However once the simulator reaches the TRAP x21 instruction, [as shown here,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p5Gzv.png) it does not work. You can see how I inputted 5 and 10 is in R0 before that instruction. Instead of printing 10, it prints nothing and shows the error `A trap was executed with an illegal vector number.` What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks!

**MY CODE:**

```
    .ORIG x3000

    LD R1, ASCII
    TRAP x23
    ADD R1, R1, R0
    AND R0, R0, #0
    ADD R0, R1, R1
    TRAP x21                            

ASCII   .FILL #-48      

    .END
```

**SOLUTION CODE:**

```
    .ORIG x3000
    LD R6, ASCII
    LD R5, NEGASCII
    TRAP x23
    ADD R1,R0,x0                                    
    ADD R1,R1,R5                            
    ADD R2,R1,R1                                    
    ADD R0,R2,R6                                    
    TRAP x21                                        
ASCII .FILL x30                                          
NEGASCII .FILL xFFD0                               
    .END
```

Comment: Your program has no ending, so it continues into your `ASCII` which accidentally decodes as `TRAP xD0`. Put an exit process trap (whatever its value is) before that. PS: doubling `5` results in `10` which is two digits so even if your conversion was correct for single digits (which it isn't) it would still not work.

Comment: Can you please elaborate why it's never ending? One of the ways to do this is shown in my edit above, but I don't see TRAP x25 there. And I will definitely have to rethink this so I can get all digits in the output.